# I want to calculate the hypotenuse of a pyramid and need a formula for doing it repetatively

Tags: geometry, 3d

I am a Star Trek geek, and I want to be able to plot courses (distances and direction based on 360x360 plotting) between different stars. I realize that spatial geometry is more difficult than 2D geometry so I have asked help here.

Comment: If by “hypothenuse” you mean that you want to compute the length of a line segment given three other line segments which are pairwise perpendicular to one another, i.e. each parallel to a coordinate axis, then a simple $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ will do the job. Otherwise you should be more specific about what exactly you want to know. Pyramid and hypotenuse aren't two terms with an obvious implicit connection.